# How to make a image stay at the bottom but not rise up

Tags: html, css, image, xhtml, background

How to make a image stay at the bottom but not rise up with css when the browser is resized or if viewed on a small screen.

Here is what I have now:
http://graves-incorporated.com/test_sites/solera2012/test/home-pg.html

It looks fine on my screen (It overlaps about 150px or so from the bottom of the main area, which is what I want), but if I shrink the screen the bottom pattern rises up too high.

Right now I just placed it as a BG image:

```
background-image: url(images/footer_pattern.png);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
background-position: bottom;
background-attachment: fixed;
```

I hope this makes sense. Please help!

Comment: Which image? Everything looks fine to mean on Chrome 15 and 1366x768.

Comment: I am talking about that faint pattern at the bottom.  The graphic designer of the site designed it to have the pattern come up from the bottom of the content.  I can post a picture if that doesn't make sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the content of your site seems to be in a fixed position, you might try and use `background-position: 0px 300px;` instead. This would keep the image in a fixed position, not locked to the bottom.

Comment: Yeah, good call! Only problem I see with that is for people with really large monitors... but I suppose I could could make the pattern a lot taller? would that work?

Comment: That would work, but it would not be optimal of course. Another alternative would be to make it big enough for most, and then gently fade it out so that it won't look horribly wrong for people with big screen.

But I'm not a real CSS wizard, and maybe there is some better solution to it all.

Comment: Also when I do that the content still floats on top of the background, it would be nice if I could lock them together some how

Comment: I figured it out, the thing giving me problems was I had position set to fixed. Thanks Allansson